# Indy's TIdMultipartFormDataStream weird behavior on Delphi XE5/Android platform

Tags: android, delphi, indy10, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to use Indy's TIdHTTP component to send data to a website.
The code works perfectly on Windows platform but unfortunately it behaves strangely on Android platform. The problem occurs when I use TIdMultipartFormDataStream to send POST parameters.

On Android platform TIdMultipartFormDataStream behaves strangely and this what happens:
Suppose your POST data is myparam=myvalue where "myparam" is parameter name and "myvalue" is the parametervalue.

The parameter values gets changed to {FIRST CHARACTER REMOVED}yvalue{NULL CHARACTER} so the final output will look like this yvalue\x00 where \x00 is a null character.

I can replace TIdMultipartFormDataStream with TStringList and I won't face such issue but I prefer to use TIdMultipartFormDataStream because it enables me to upload files + send POST data at the same time.

Sample code:

```
procedure HTTPPOST;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  POSTData: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  POSTData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;

  try
    POSTData.AddFile('myfile','file.txt'); // works
    POSTData.AddFormField('username', 'user1'); // On Android the value gets changed to ser1\x00 where \x00 = Null character

    HTTP.Post('http://www.example.com', POSTData)

  finally
    POSTData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Note:** the code was tested using Delphi XE5 and Delphi XE5 Update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a `ZEROBASEDSTRINGS` bug, which should not exist in the current SVN version because Indy disables `ZEROBASEDSTRINGS` globally in all of its units after it kept suffering from lots of ZBS bugs in XE4. So I do suggest you upgrade to the lastest SVN verson.  If you are having problems doing so, please update your question with details explaining why

Comment: The one which I tried to compile was the ZIP version from http://indy.fulgan.com and it seems it had a problem. I have tried the SVN version and didn't face the same issue and I was able to compile Indy for Android platform although it wasn't straight forward like when you compile it for Windows platform. I ended up installing it the dirty way and it's working without any issue. Thanks Remy :)

Comment: The Fulgan zip is updated with the latest SVN code every night.

Answer (score 0):

Works..

```
procedure HTTPPOST;
    var
      HTTP: TIdHTTP;
      POSTData: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
    begin
      HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      POSTData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;

      try
        POSTData.AddFile('myfile','file.txt'); // works
        POSTData.AddFormField('username', UTF8Encode('user1'), 'utf-8').ContentTransfer:= '8bit';

        HTTP.Post('http://www.example.com', POSTData)

      finally
        POSTData.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. As because this is a relative old question, can you provide some extra information about why this solution works?